# WPF How to fire DependencyProperty from menuitem click

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I checked around but could not find any answer. I hope someone can help.
Here is my code... What I want to do is:if the menu item is checked I will disable the tooltip if it is unchecked I will enable back the tooltip but the problem is I am using DependencyProperty .

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IngredientProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Ingredient", typeof(IngredientData), typeof(ChannelControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IngredientData.GetEmpty(),FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(IngredientChanged)));

public static void IngredientChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
//....
```

}

and my XAML...

```
<ToolTip x:Key="IngredientToolTip">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource IngredientTextStyle}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ingredient.Concentration, StringFormat=Concentration:{0}%}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>...
```

What I want to do is, I have a menuitem that is checkable if it is checked I want to disable the tooltip and if it is unchecked I want to enable the tooltip. i am able to disable it but I am not able to display back the tooltip.
here is my click..

```
private void ShowAltMenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
     if(sender.isChecked)
           chn.IngredientBorder.ToolTip = null;
      else
         //Now if the menuitem is unchecked then i should display the tool tip.
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this with some property binding? Setting the Tooltip property to null in an event handler looks wrong to me.

Comment: You're making the tooltip null and expecting it to know how to make it 'un-null'. You need to create some sort of binding or property that can then be referenced again programmatically. Possibly have a list of enums that are referenced using the sender's ID and get the value using Reflection.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)